# Render a rails model custom getter using react.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I've started playing a bit with the react-rails gem and am struggling to understand why I am unable to render a custom model attribute in react.js.

All database persisted attributes work fine, it's just custom getters that are returning nothing.

For the sake of simplicity, here's my `User` model with `email, first_name and last_name` as persisted attributes.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def full_name_and_email
    "#{first_name} #{last_name} (#{email})"
  end

end
```

When rendering my view, I initialize a react component:

```
<%= react_component 'Header', { data: current_user } %>
```

And within the `Header` component, if I try the following inside the render function:

```
var user = this.props.data;
...
return(
    <p>Welcome {user.email}</p>
)
```

My rendered HTML is:

```
<p data-reactid=".0.0.2">
    <span data-reactid=".0.0.2.0">Welcome </span>
    <span data-reactid=".0.0.2.1">super_admin@email.com</span>
</p>
```

However if I try

```
render(    
    <p>Welcome {user.full_name_and_email}</p>
)
```

My rendered HTML results in

```
<p data-reactid=".0.0.2">
    <span data-reactid=".0.0.2.0">Welcome </span>
</p>
```

I'm probably missing something pretty basic here so if anyone could please help me understand what's going on it would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question after re-reading the documentation for the gem:

> props is either an object that responds to #to_json or an
>   already-stringified JSON object (eg, made with Jbuilder, see note
>   below).

And to add methods to to_json

```
current_user.to_json(methods: :full_name_and_email)
```